# How to marshal array with one element with different type into JSON with Go?

Tags: json, go

I need this result of JSON marshal:

```
["a", "b", ["c", "d"], "e"]
```

How correctly to do this in Go?

Comment: What is your input data structure? What have you tried? What problems do you have? Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: I have to send this kind of data to external api.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to creating a slice/array of mixed types is to use the empty interface type that go offers

```
inner := []string{"c", "d"}
all := []interface{}{"a", "b", inner, "e"}
```

And then just `json.Marshal` the interface slice. This works because any and all values implement at least an empty interface. You can use the most bloated object as though it doesn't have any methods/receiver functions to call. That's why people sometimes refer to go's `interface{}` type as being a *"generic"* type. A lot of abstract stuff that packages do use `interface{}` arguments, and then reflection to work out what was actually passed. Just look at the source of the encoding/json package and see how it unmarshals values...

https://play.golang.org/p/96VVo2F1m7

Unmarshalling would work in pretty much the same way: you can unmarshal JSON strings into `interface{}` variables. You may need to use type-assertions and/or reflection to be able to work with the data though. That's why it's probably best to create types...

Answer (score 0):

You ca use a slice of `interface{}`, for example https://play.golang.org/p/c8dPRPK6mr

Comment: While your answer is correct, I believe OP was more interested in starting out with typed data (ie values that aren't `interface{}`, and how to marshal those. You're unmarshaling to empty interfaces and directly marshalling back, leaving out that all values can be cast to ìnterface{}`